# .Net Core MVC exception filter

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

i used try catch for handling errors in my project.I did that for every action method.I want to create a filter for that.It needs to catch the error and print it on the error page.

[image]

this is my error model.

[image]

this is the error view.It takes the error and print it.
How can i achieve it with the onException method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, if you want to use exception filter to achieve your requirement, I suggest you could try below codes:

public class SampleExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter
{
private readonly IHostEnvironment _hostEnvironment;

```
    public SampleExceptionFilter(IHostEnvironment hostEnvironment) =>
        _hostEnvironment = hostEnvironment;

    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary<ErrorViewModel>(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), context.ModelState);
        viewData = new ViewDataDictionary<ErrorViewModel>(viewData, new ErrorViewModel { exception = context.Exception });

         //here we go

        var res = new ViewResult()
        {
            ViewName = "Error",
            ViewData = viewData
        };
        context.Result = res;

    }
}
```

Then use it inside the controller:

```
[TypeFilter(typeof(SampleExceptionFilter))]
public class HomeController : Controller
```

Result:

[image]